# Sqoop import to hive (Hortonworks) "Show Tables" no results externally

Tags: java, hive, sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I am using Hortonworks latest version. I ran the following Sqoop command.

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://myIp;database=myDatabase"
--username "myUsername"
--password "myPassword"
--driver "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
--table "TmpTable"
--hive-import
```

When I run the command in Hortonworks command line `hive -e "show tables"` I get my table that was imported from sqoop and 2 other tables named sample_07 and sample_08. (I can run this command from any directory)

When I run the following java code from an external source (Ports are opened).

```
private ResultSet runQueryAndGetResult() throws SQLException{
        try {
            String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
            Class.forName(driverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://"+hiveHostName + ":" +hiveForwardedPort + "/default", "", "");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "show tables";
        System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        System.out.println("Query execution complete");
        return res;
    }
```

I get no rows back and no errors. I also was reading that some people were talking about see the data in hadoops location /user/hive/warehouse but when I run the following command `hadoop fs -ls /user/hive` there are no files in the hive folder..... So I am not sure what is going on. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction because at this point I am stuck.

Comment: Your JDBC client connects to HiveServer2, which connects in turn to the Metastore; but your `hive` CLI (and `sqoop` CLI) connect directly to the Metastore based on their local config. So my best guess is that HiverServer2 configuration is not correct i.e. it does not connect to your Metastore... and falls back silently to "sandbox mode", using an (empty) Derby embedded database as Metastore.

Comment: Try running this command in `hive`, in `beeline -u <URL>` and in your Java client: `set hive.metastore.uris ;`

Comment: What is the URL that I am supposed to be using? Sorry, I am very new at this stuff, not even sure what beeline is lol...

Comment: Btw, I found my hive metastore.... it is at /apps/hive/warehouse. And the hive.metastore.uris is thrift://sandbox.hortonworks.com:9083. I found all of this information on the Ambari webpage at localhost:8080. There is a ton of information here if you want to know any of it to better diagnose it.

Comment: OMG. The Metastore is a **service** backed by a **database** (Derby by default, a more solid choice would be MySQL or PostgreSQL, or even Oracle). The purpose is to store **metadata** (i.e. table logical / physical structure: column names, column types, file format, storage location, partitioning rules...) globally.

Comment: The `hive` CLI *(command-line interface)* is a **fat client** that connects to the Metastore, compiles HQL queries, breaks the query into MapReduce jobs, and updates the Metastore if necessary. HiveServer2 is a **service** that does exactly the same, but on behalf of  **thin clients** that connect to HS2 using JDBC. And `beeline` is a command-line tool, that works exactly like `hive` except that Beeline is a thin client that connects to HS2.

Comment: On the other hand, `/apps/hive/warehouse` is an HDFS **directory**; it is the usual **storage root location** for Hive data -- add one sub-directory for each Database, then one sub-sub-dir for each "managed" Table *(EXTERNAL tables are a bit different)*, then 1..N additional levels for partitions if the table is partitioned.

Comment: I understand all of this now but I am still having the issue of connecting externally.....